# Get rid of X-CSRF-Token in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, token, restful-authentication

I need to design a RESTful API for Rails, which will enable login from web browser, smart phone, tablet, etc. When I do login it always require X-CSRF-Token, so everytime I need to use session or cookie info. However the REST api should be stateless, which means shouldn't use cookies. Is there a way to get rid of that? Any suggestion for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I dealt with this in an app that responds with both HTML and JSON.  I want the CSRF check except if it's an API call from a trusted source, so

application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
  # has to come after the protect_from_forgery line
  skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token, :if => :api_request?

  # but don't just accept any URL with a .json extension, you need something else to
  # ensure your caller is trusted (in this case I test for a valid API key being passed)
  before_filter :api_key_valid?, :if => :api_request?

  def api_request?
    request.format == 'application/json'
  end

  # ... etc
end
```